# index.js: Cannot find module '.../@react-native-community/cli/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformation/src/index.js' (null))

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

I  am trying to add react-native-navigation@ v2 in my project but it is giving me this error. Can someone tell me why does this Happening??

this is my Package.json

```
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "metro-react-native-babel-transformer": "^0.53.1",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.4",
    "react-native-navigation": "^2.17.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.4.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.4.3",
    "babel-jest": "24.7.1",
    "jest": "24.7.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.53.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have `babel.config.js` file in the root directory of your project instead of `babel.rc`and the file `babel.config.js` should have the following contents.

```
module.exports = {
   presets: ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
}
```